# How to mask PII data using DMS without adding a column

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, dms

I am replicating data from source db to target db within two different AWS accounts. I am using transformation rules for this but unable to do it. Because I don't want to add new column and delete the old one which contains PII data.

I want to mask and replicate the column data to target db during ongoing replication in same column which contains PII data.